# Pandas - Remove index column

Tags: python, pandas

How can I remove the index column from a dataframe loaded by Pandas?
I have tried this:
`df_total = pd.read_csv(" ... ", index_col=False])`,
but Pandas continues to add automatically an index column on the left.

Comment: It is impossible, but you can set some column as index. You need always index in pandas.

Comment: What don't you like about it?  Do you not like seeing it when it's printed out?  Do you hate that `pandas` is keeping track of row positions?  What is it you are trying to do such that a dataframe having an index gets in the way.

Comment: I'm trying to insert these data as input for a neural network, and seems that it recognizes one column more.

Comment: Post your code for the neural network, it's unlikely to be a pandas issue here, you only have a certain number of columns

Comment: Also note that this `df_total = pd.read_csv(" ... ", index_col=False])` is upcasting the `False` to an int `0`, you want `df_total = pd.read_csv(" ... ", index_col=None])` or don't include it as the default is to not assume the csv has an index

Comment: Yes, I have changed it. I'm sorry, but probably the issue it's not about Pandas's index, but it's regarding my neural network. I have opened another post about it.

Comment: Pandas always keeps track of an index column as said above. If you want to have access to the underlying data of the pandas dataframe consider `df.values`, where `df` is a dataframe instance. This returns the data without any index column as a numpy array.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df_total = pd.read_csv("xx.csv", index_col=0)
```

And it will use the first column as index.

Comment: when you do that, that first column is no longer accessible by normal df['col name'] syntax :(